# How to fetch newly added rows in postgres tables in faster way using python

Tags: python, postgresql, psql

We have a postgres database table where every second 50 rows will be added to that table continously from a realtime application. Now we have read every newly added row(one row at a time) using python script. Is it possible read all the rows without missing any?

If possible, please help me with python script to read realtime updated rows(50 rows/second) from postgres database.

Tried below script.

```
    print('\nConnecting to the PostgreSQL database...\n')
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    
    # create a cursor
    cur = conn.cursor()
    
    while TRUE:
        cur.execute('SELECT * from postgrestable ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1')
        result = cur.fetchone();  
        print(result)

    #Commit your changes in the database
    conn.commit()
```

Response : Database access is working but i am able get a row every to seconds. Every 2 seconds my database id getting 100 rows. But i am able to fetch only 1 row out of 100.

Is this because of cur.execute() function? Will this function takes time to execute?

Comment: why you commented `cur.execute(...)`? Why you need commit if you dont change anything? Why you need `time.sleep` if you want it faster?

Comment: @Alex OP needs to commit to pick up newly added rows (although configuring the connection to use autocommit might be better, depending on their use case).

Comment: @snakecharmerb he dont need commit, he already has connection to db. Commit only for you changes.

Comment: if you want get new rows in loop then you need `cur.execute("SELECT ...")` inside loop to get new data. You can get in loop all new rows that appears in table by checking count of rows with cursor. But specifically get 50 new rows every 1 second would be hard to implement because operation could take more than 1 second (there a lot of factors)

Comment: Also you maybe need to order by selected rows to get new rows with fetchone

Comment: @Alex it depends on the transaction isolation level

Comment: Sorry its a mistake from my side. "cur.execute('SELECT * from postgrestable')" - this line is not commented.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check it and give me a answer.

Comment: Have you considered using LISTEN/NOTIFY?

Comment: @jjanes Yes I have tried LISTEN/NOTIFY now. I can get the newly added row through notify.payload string. The issue is I have floating point value column also in my table. As the payload I am getting is a single continous string. I am facing difficulties to extract only the floating point value. And is it possible to use LISTEN/NOTIFY on Postgres VIEWS.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your python client to [`listen`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-listen.html) to [`pg_notify()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html#id-1.9.3.158.7.5) broadcasted from a [`trigger...after insert or update`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) on the table collecting your signals.

```
create table table_all_signals (
    source_id int not null,
    signal_id uuid default gen_random_uuid() primary key,
    signal_timestamp timestamp not null,
    value numeric not null );

create function f_signal_collector()returns trigger as $f$
begin perform pg_notify('incoming_signals_feed',to_jsonb(new)::text);
      return new;
end $f$ language plpgsql;

create trigger t_signal_collector after insert or update on table_all_signals
for each row execute function f_signal_collector();
```

A sample insert will trigger a message to be relayed to your listening client:

> Asynchronous notification "incoming_signals_feed" with payload "{"value": 830.912026524988, "signal_id": "ce2d72e0-a707-4ab5-8162-b37c0063d471", "source_id": 1, "signal_timestamp": "2023-11-23T09:01:09.308965"}" received from server process with PID 1209744.

To work around the fact you can send only `text` payload via `notify` you can instead relay only the unique identifier for your client

```
create or replace function f_signal_collector()returns trigger as $f$
begin perform pg_notify('incoming_signals_feed',new.signal_id::text);
      return new;
end $f$ language plpgsql;
```

> Asynchronous notification "incoming_signals_feed" with payload "2a20ce9b-f077-45ec-a85a-b88fb54d6d0f" received from server process with PID 1209744.

Then let it simply go pick it up:

```
select * from table_all_signals where signal_id='2a20ce9b-f077-45ec-a85a-b88fb54d6d0f';
```

And let psycopg2 handle the binding.

Comment: I want to fetch every new row irrespective of SignalID. My table will be inserted with 50 rows per second.

Comment: @Balaji This does allow you to fetch every row, regardless of their SignalID - the first example broadcasts the whole row straight away. I mention `where signal_id` as a workaround if you don't want to broadcast the new row as `text` directly from `notify`. Instead, you can broadcast those fields of the row that uniquely identify it, and let the client catch them and use them to fetch that row the standard way, without interfacing through `text`. Above, I made SignalID unique, but that's just an example - in your case you can pass singal_id and signal_timestamp and later select based on those

Answer (score -1):

Try this updated code, in this code I replaced **OrderBy: [asc(document.columns.latestUpdatedAt)]** with **orderBy: [desc(document.columns.latestUpdatedAt)]** . You'll get the latest chat rooms first because this will sort the result set according to the latestUpdatedAt column in descending order.

```
import psycopg2
import time

# Connection parameters
params = {
    'dbname': 'your_database_name',
    'user': 'your_username',
    'password': 'your_password',
    'host': 'your_host',
    'port': 'your_port'
}

# Connect to the PostgreSQL database
print('\nConnecting to the PostgreSQL database...\n')
conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)

# Create a cursor
cur = conn.cursor()

# Initial value for the last processed primary key or timestamp
last_processed_id = 0  # Assuming the primary key is an integer

while True:
    # Fetch new rows based on the primary key or timestamp
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM postgrestable WHERE id > %s ORDER BY id', (last_processed_id,))
    
    # Fetch all new rows
    new_rows = cur.fetchall()
    
    # Process the new rows
    for row in new_rows:
        print(row)
        # Update the last processed primary key or timestamp
        last_processed_id = row[0]  # Assuming the primary key is the first column
    
    # Sleep for a short duration before checking for new rows again
    time.sleep(1/50)

# Close the cursor and connection (not reached in this example due to the infinite loop)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: In our table id column values are same. id won't increment or change for every row. And we have 3 columns in our table id, timestamp and value. I have tried the above provided script. Its not fetching the lastest rows. Instead it fetching the starting rows(old rows).

Comment: And I have edited my question and I have updated the python script. Please check it and give me a solution.

Comment: This won't be reliable because rows do not need to become visible strictly in order of id.